# Error URL in mvc 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Need help. This is Routeconfig:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "camera",
    url: "danh-muc/{CategoryName}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Product", action = "CategoryPro", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, namespaces: new[] { "ThietBiAnNinh.Controllers" }
);
```

This is my menu:

```
<b href="danh-muc/hd-tv">HD-TV</b>
<b href="danh-muc/led-tv">HD-TV</b>
<b href="danh-muc/lgd-tv">HD-TV</b>
```

When i clicked into link example `<b href="danh-muc/hd-tv">HD-TV</b>`
it'll call url `http://localhost:50177/danh-muc/danh-muc/hd-tv`

Comment: Because you're missing the leading slash (`/danh-muc/hd-tv`) that will make you path absolute. However, you really should use `Url.Action()` for this purpose (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action(v=vs.118).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You need a leading slash to show that it's a root directory. However, a much better idea would be to use `@Html.ActionLink`. It's a cleaner and easier way to link :-)